# Regular expression-like languages to search and replace in *tree-like* structures or even graphs

Tags: search, replace, tree, programming-languages

First such example is XSLT. Second example may be a hypothetical language that is basically well-known regular expression language, but additionally has a special construct that matches any number of _*balanced*_ parenthesis. (Note the difference of approaches of first and second example — first one transforms trees, while the second one transforms strings that are treated as trees. Also, this hypothetical language seems to me to be very useful.)

I do know that there are a lot of such languages, but the importance of tree-like structures in programmers' job and convenience of match and replace approach justifies such a broad question.

Please do not tell about languages with closed source implementation or implementation, severely restricted in other ways. However, if you know really nice language without working implementation, it may be worth to mention. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another language, which is an alternative to XSLT for searching, transforming, and generating XML data, is XQuery (with XQuery Update).